# Why are the number of pivot columns in $V$ equal to the dimension of the span of the column vectors of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix $V$ with dimensions $m \times n$ in echelon form.

> Why are the number of pivot columns in $V$ equal to the dimension of the span of the column vectors of $V$?

For the case where are there are no non-pivot columns (i.e. no free variables), we know that $\vec{c} = \vec{0}$ is the only solution to $V\vec{c} = \vec{0}$, implying linear independence. Thus, we can infer that the column vectors of $V$ span the entire space $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ is the number of pivot columns.

When there are $\geq 1$ non-pivot columns (i.e. free variables), we know that there will be non-trivial solutions to $V\vec{c} = \vec{0}$, implying that the column vectors span some space $\mathbb{R}^{t}$ where $t < n$. I was told, however, that the exact value of $t$ is the same as the number of pivot columns in $V$.

My very vague intuition tells me that this is because pivot columns correspond to basic variables, and that since basic variables can be written in terms of free variables, the number of basic variables tells us about how many coefficients $c_{i}$ in $\vec{c}$ can be written as a linear combination of others in the vector equation for $V\vec{c} = \vec{0}$. Thus, as there is a relation between the number of vectors in a set that can be written as a linear combination of others and the dimension of the span of the vectors in the set, the above fact holds true. However, I would appreciate it if someone could help build stronger intuition for this fact.

On a side note, it also holds true that the number of non-pivot columns corresponds to the dimension of the solution set $\vec{x}$ in $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$. I'm not sure if the two facts above are related, but if they are, I would appreciate it if one could build some intuition for this fact as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 4 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Columns 1 and 3 are pivot columns; I'll say that columns 2, 4, 5 are "free" columns.

If you write a column-vector $v$ like this one:
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
1\\
v_3 \\
2 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then writing out $Mv = 0$ gives
$$
1v_1 + 3\cdot 1 + 0 v_3 + 4 \cdot 2 + 6 \cdot -1 = 0\\
0 v_1 + 0 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot v_3 + 2 \cdot 2 + 5 \cdot -1 = 0
$$
Cleaning that up a little, you get
$$
v_1 + 3 + 8 - 6  = 0\\
v_3 + 4 - 5 = 0
$$
i.e.,  a pair of equations, one per row, and each equation determines the value of exactly one of the two "pivot" variables, i.e., the entries of $v$ whose index corresponds to a pivot column.

Now suppose I'd chosen a different set of numbers to put in the "free" spots of $v$, say, $1$, $0$, and $0$. The equations I'd get would be
$$
v_1 + 3 = 0\\
v_3 +0 = 0
$$
so that we'd have
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1\\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as a solution to $Mv = 0$. I could also put in the values $0,1,0$, getting equations
$$
v_1 + 4 = 0 \\
v_3 + 2 = 0
$$
and a resulting vector
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
0\\
-2 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Doing that one more time, I'd get a third vector
$$
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
-6 \\
0\\
-5 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Once you examine these for a moment you notice a pattern: when I set the FIRST free-variable to 1 and the other two to zero, the "pivot" entries of $v$ are just the negatives of the numbers in the first "free" column;when I set the SECOND free-var to 1 and the other two to zero, the pivot entries are the negatives of the numbers in the SECOND free column, and so on.

So through this process, I've generated three solutions to the equation $Mv = 0$. Let's call them $z_1, z_2,$ and $z_3$. And there are *three* because there were three free variables.

Now let's look back at that very first solution, the one I got before picking clever values for the free variables. I used the values $1, 2,$ and $-1$, right? Let's look at
$$
1 w_1 + 2 w_2 + (-1)w_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1\\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + 2 \begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
0\\
-2 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + (-1) \begin{bmatrix}
-6 \\
0\\
-5 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1\\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is exactly the thing we came up with for our first solution.

In fact, *any* solution $q$ to $Mv = 0$ will have some three values, $c_1, c_2, c_3$ in the "free variable" positions, and it'll turn out that
$$
q = c_1w_1+ c_2 w_2 + c_3 w_3.
$$

So the three $w$-vectors "span" the solution space, whose dimension is therefore no more than 3. To show it's exactly 3, we have to show that the $w$-vectors are linearly independent, i.e., that if
$$
d_1 w_1 + d_2 w_2 + d_3 w_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0\\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then all of the $d$s are zero. That equation turns into 5 equations for the $d_i$s:
$$
\begin{align}
d_1 \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
1\\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + d_2 \begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
0\\
-2 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} + d_3 \begin{bmatrix}
-6 \\
0\\
-5 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0\\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}
$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
\
-3 d_1 -4 d_2 -6 d_3 &= 0\
1 d_1 + 0d_2 + 0 d_3 &= 0\
0 d_1 + 2 d_2 + 5 d_3 &= 0\
0 d_1 + 1d_2 + 0 d_3 &= 0\
0 d_1 + 0d_2 + 1 d_3 &= 0
\end{align}
The 2nd, 4th, and 5th of these (because 2, 4, 5 are the free variables!) say that $d_1, d_2,$ and $d_3$ are all zero. So these three $w$-vectors are linearly independent and span the solution space for $Mv = 0$; hence the dimension of that space is three.

A rather similar argument says that if you take the pivot columns of $M$, they must span the column-space, because each of the "free" columns can be expressed as a combination of the pivot-columns. Example: the column $\pmatrix{ 6\\5} $ is just 6 times the first pivot column plus 5 times the second one. Hence the pivot columns are a basis for the column space (OK, you have to prove linear independence, but that's easy), so the dimension fo the column space is the number of pivot columns.

And that's about it.